# Did Abraham Lincoln say "I would rather be a little nobody, then to be a evil somebody."?

Tags: quotes

According to [this page](http://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/229.Abraham_Lincoln?page=2) and 2800+ others, Abraham Lincoln said:

> “I would rather be a little nobody, then to be a evil somebody.” (sic)

I could not find a source. Did Abraham Lincoln say it, or is it just someone that attributed it to him?

Comment: It seems unlikely that Lincoln would have been so ungrammatical. There is a tendency for people to take phrases they like the sound of and falsely attribute them to people they, and others, revere. Unfortunately, most collections of quotations omit any reference to original sources and apparently recycle the contents of other collections without checking their authenticity.

Comment: Tracking down quotes are REALLY difficult. I am currently working on tracking down another quote than this one. I have no idea how to find out if Lincoln said that or not. Proving it false is harder than to prove it right.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: the precise wording is clearly wrong, but with the obvious errors fixed — as e.g. “I would rather be a little nobody, than an evil somebody” — it becomes something that Lincoln certainly could have said, at least on purely linguistic grounds.  The use of *nobody* and *somebody* as nouns in this sense is attested back to the 16th century (according to [the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/127502)), and was well-established by Lincoln’s time.

Comment: Henry Clay, a politician whom Lincoln admired as his "ideal of a great man" was [widely attributed](https://books.google.com/books?id=w81L1qAhNjoC&q=%22i+would+rather+be+right%22#v=snippet&q=%22i%20would%20rather%20be%20right%22&f=false) in Lincoln's day with the saying: "I would rather be right than be president." The similarity is interesting, but not close enough to draw any conclusions.

Comment: Lincoln *did* say [this](http://www.abrahamlincolnonline.org/lincoln/speeches/1832.htm): "But, Fellow-Citizens, I shall conclude.--Considering the great degree of modesty which should always attend youth, it is probable I have already been more presuming than becomes me. However, upon the subjects of which I have treated, I have spoken as I thought. I may be wrong in regard to any or all of them; but holding it a sound maxim, that it is better to be only sometimes right, than at all times wrong, so soon as I discover my opinions to be erroneous, I shall be ready to renounce them.

Comment: Every man is said to have his peculiar ambition. Whether it be true or not, I can say for one that I have no other so great as that of being truly esteemed of my fellow men, by rendering myself worthy of their esteem. How far I shall succeed in gratifying this ambition, is yet to be developed. I am young and unknown to many of you. I was born and have ever remained in the most humble walks of life. I have no wealthy or popular relations to recommend me.

Comment: My case is thrown exclusively upon the independent voters of this county, and if elected they will have conferred a favor upon me, for which I shall be unremitting in my labors to compensate. But if the good people in their wisdom shall see fit to keep me in the back ground, I have been too familiar with disappointments to be very much chagrined."

Comment: In that light, I think it would be fairly safe to say that Lincoln *would* have said something like the quote in the OP, even if he did not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given its simplicity and popularity (currently over 9000 results on Google, including the correct "than" version), there should be a reputable source for the quote. I am still unable to locate one, so the answer is most likely: **No, Abraham Lincoln did not say that.**

Quotes are so often [falsely attributed](https://www.one.org/us/2014/10/30/why-you-shouldnt-always-trust-social-media-for-your-world-news-and-views/) to Abraham Lincoln, famous for his honesty, that he's become the icon of a [popular meme](https://www.google.nl/search?q="don%27t+believe"+meme+%2B"abraham+lincoln"):

[image: Fake quote meme featuring Abraham Lincoln]